# Woocommerce : programmatically set a discount for the first item ordered, but inventory based

Tags: woocommerce, inventory, discount

I'm building a website where i'll sell some fine art prints and i would like to set an automated discount when a customer buy the first print of a serie. Each of my prints are limited to 15 pieces and i would like to set a 30% discount for the first sell (#1/15) of each series. Then, for the next prints (#2 to #15), price goes back to normal.

**Edit :**

I did progress on my problem ! I did some research and tried a lot of different things and i found how to set the custom price i wanted on my product page (regular price + discount price) with the rule to only apply it if the related item available stock is 15.

[regular price + discount price](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZFEM.jpg)

And here's the code is used :

```html
// Generating the product "regular price"
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_get_regular_price', 'dynamic_regular_price', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_variation_get_regular_price', 'dynamic_regular_price', 10, 2 );
function dynamic_regular_price( $regular_price, $product ) {
    
    $stock_qte = $product->get_stock_quantity();
    if( empty($regular_price) || $regular_price == 0 )
        return $product->get_price();
    else
        return $regular_price;
}


// Generating the product "sale price"
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_get_sale_price', 'dynamic_sale_price', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_variation_get_sale_price', 'dynamic_sale_price', 10, 2 );
function dynamic_sale_price( $sale_price, $product ) {
    
    $stock_qte = $product->get_stock_quantity();
    if( $stock_qte == '15')
        return $product-> get_regular_price() * 0.7;
    else
        //return $product->get_regular_price();
        return $regular_price;
};

// Displayed formatted regular price + sale price
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'dynamic_sale_price_html', 20, 2 );
function dynamic_sale_price_html( $price_html, $product ) {
    
    $stock_qte = $product->get_stock_quantity();
    if( $stock_qte == '15')
        $price_html = wc_format_sale_price( wc_get_price_to_display( $product, array( 'price' => $product->get_regular_price() ) ), wc_get_price_to_display(  $product, array( 'price' => $product->get_sale_price() ) ) ) . $product->get_price_suffix();
    else
        $price_html = wc_price(wc_get_price_to_display( $product, array( 'price' => $product->get_regular_price() ) ). $product->get_price_suffix());
    return $price_html;
}
```

It's almost working but the code related to the cart values updates is not fully working. The cart sub-total is good and take count of the discount but the individual price of each product is not updated and shown as without discount. It's the same on the cart page.

[cart (from mini cart)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jTcWi.jpg)
[cart (cart page)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j222j.jpg)

```html
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'alter_price_cart', 9999 );
function alter_price_cart( $cart ) {
 
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ) return;
    
    if ( did_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' ) >= 2 ) return;
 
    // IF CUSTOMER NOT LOGGED IN, DONT APPLY DISCOUNT
    //if ( ! wc_current_user_has_role( 'customer' ) ) return;
 
    // LOOP THROUGH CART ITEMS & APPLY 30% DISCOUNT
    foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
        $product = $cart_item['data'];
        $price = $product->get_price();
        $cart_item['data']->set_price( $price * 0.7 );
    }
}
```

I'll also have to add the stock availability logic for the mini-cart / cart / checkout page but i'll do that in a second time.

I must have made some mistakes in the loop throught the cart but i cannot catch the issue :( Any idea about how to hook the price of each product and change the displayed value ?

Have a nice day,

Quentin

Comment: For context: other than the number, the prints are the same WooCommerce product?  Are you setting the stock/inventory to 15 pieces to avoid more being bought?
If not, how are you limiting the amounts for sale?

Comment: Each print is represented by an individual variable product (size and framing choices) and the inventory is limited at 15 at the product level. Restocking order option is not allowed to avoid ordering already ended series.